# How to change game language?

Tags: super-smash-bros-4

I'm using the system console with language set to spanish (NTSC) but I like to change the game language to english, is this possible?

Comment: I don't know about SSB specifically, but usually Wii & Wii U games simply follow the system settings.

Comment: Hmmm... I would gladly get rid of that Spanish narrator too :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [SSB Wiki](http://www.ssbwiki.com/Language#In_Super_Smash_Bros._4) states:

> The NTSC version can be set to English, French or Spanish. As with Brawl, the language is dependent on the console's set language and cannot be changed in-game.